# How to build a index page for all user-defined julia functions?

Tags: markdown, julia, documentation, doxygen

Say I have `A.jl`, `B.jl`, `C.jl`, `D.jl`. In each .jl, there are 100 functions. When I try to call a specific function, I need to search the .jl to figure out how is the function defined? Is there an easy way that can generate all function definitions into an HTML index page. If I can click the link and view the actual source code for the function, it will be even better. Something like the Doxygen generate docs for C/C++, but Doxygen does not support Julia. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The build-in support for documenting function is actually quite good in my opinion.

1. Basically you use "docstrings": https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/documentation/#Documentation-1

   ```
   """
       s = mysum(a,b)

   Compute the sum of `a` and `b`.
   """
   function mysum(a,b)
       return a+b
   end
   ```
2. It might be useful to put the functions in a module (A, B, C and D could be separate modules). You load a module with `using A` or `import A` (the file `A.jl` should be in your `LOAD_PATH`). If you use, `import` the function are prefixed with the module name separated by a dot. If the functions are not grouped in a module, you need to include the file containing the functions, e.g. `include("A.jl")` (using a full or relative path).
3. The documentation can be displayed by `?`, for example `?myfunction_in_module_A` or `?A.myfunction_in_module_A` once the module is loaded.
4. If you do not remember a function name

   - you can make a full-text search with `apropos("my keyword")`.
   - list all function is a module with `names(module_A)`
   - make a search based on a involved type using `methodswith`
5. [Documenter.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDocs/Documenter.jl) allows to make pretty documentation by combining all docsstrings into a single HTML document.

Comment: Just would like to add: A module is not necessarily needed. You can load a file with `include` and then you can go as in 3 or as below.  
After 1 and 2, if you are using Juno, you can get the documentation via context menu on the editor or via keyboard shortcut. If you are using an IJulia Notebook, you can use Shift+Tab shortcut to get the documentation.

You can also jump to definition directly after 2 on Juno.

You do not need to write a docstring if you just need the signature of the function; `?myfunction` will still show you how the function is declared.

Comment: I didn't investigate further, but seen the "docstrings" looks a bit like python documentation possibilities. Maybe in doxygen the use of EXTENSION_MAPPING fromjl to python might work..

Comment: @Hchr, you are right, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to call a specific function, I need to search the .jl to
>   figure out how is the function defined? Is there an easy way that can
>   generate all function definitions into an HTML index page. If I can
>   click the link and view the actual source code for the function, it
>   will be even better.

Not directly answering the question about an index page, but if your goal is to easily find the source code, then the goto option is to use the `@which` and `@edit` macros. From the help:

```
help?> @which
  @which

  Applied to a function or macro call, it evaluates the arguments to the
  specified call, and returns the Method object for the method that would be
  called for those arguments. Applied to a variable, it returns the module in
  which the variable was bound. It calls out to the which function.


help?> @edit
  @edit

  Evaluates the arguments to the function or macro call, determines their
  types, and calls the edit function on the resulting expression.
```

As an example, lets see where the `sum` method for summing an array is defined

```
julia> @which sum([1, 2, 3])
sum(a::AbstractArray) in Base at reducedim.jl:627
```

Alternatively we could use `@edit`, which would then open the corresponding source file at the correct line

```
julia> @edit sum([1, 2, 3])
```

If you want to change which editor will be used to open the file, set the `JUILA_EDITOR` environment variable, for example, to use Sublime, I would do

```
julia> ENV["JULIA_EDITOR"] = "subl"
"subl"
```

Comment: It might be worth adding `less()¬ and `methods()` to this list of useful functions.